# Add Expiry to Redis Cache

Tags: c#, caching, redis

I have implemented Redis Cache in my C# project. I would just like to know how i can overload my `Get<T>` to also accept a timeout value. I figured this would be the best way to add an expiry to my redis cache provider. 
Here is my code Below:

```
public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string key)
{
    return (await _cacheClient.Db0.GetAsync<T>(key).ConfigureAwait(false));
}
/// <summary>
/// Fetch item from cache
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Return Type</typeparam>
/// <param name="key">Key identifier in cache</param>
/// <returns>Cached item</returns>
public T Get<T>(string key)
{
    return AsyncHelper.RunSync(() => _cacheClient.Db0.GetAsync<T>(key));

}

/// <summary>
/// Fetch from cache, else execute operation and cache
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Return Type</typeparam>
/// <param name="key">Key identifier in cache</param>
/// <param name="method">Method to execute</param>
/// <param name="args">Method args</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string key, Delegate method, params object[] args)
{
    T result = default(T);

    try
    {
        if (await _cacheClient.Db0.ExistsAsync(key))
        {
            return await _cacheClient.Db0.GetAsync<T>(key);
        }
        else
        {
            result = ExecMethod<T>(method, args);
            await _cacheClient.Db0.AddAsync(key, result);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logHandler.LogError($"Error fetching cache for key:{key}", ex);
        result = ExecMethod<T>(method, args);
    }

    return result;
}
/// <summary>
/// Fetch from cache, else execute operation and cache
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Return Type</typeparam>
/// <param name="key">Key identifier in cache</param>
/// <param name="method">Method to execute</param>
/// <param name="args">Method args</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public T Get<T>(string key, Delegate method, params object[] args)
{
    T result = default(T);

    try
    {

        if (AsyncHelper.RunSync(() => _cacheClient.Db0.ExistsAsync(key)))
        {
            result = AsyncHelper.RunSync(() => _cacheClient.Db0.GetAsync<T>(key));
        }
        else
        {
            result = ExecMethod<T>(method, args);
            var added = AsyncHelper.RunSync(() => _cacheClient.Db0.AddAsync(key, result));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logHandler.LogError($"Error fetching cache for key:{key}", ex);
        result = ExecMethod<T>(method, args);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: It is better to use `Add` with expiration, so that Readis can handle the expiration by itselt.

Comment: I mean every where you add a key to redis it should be added with an expiration, so every time you fetch the key, if it is expired, the result is null.

Comment: what redis client API is this? it matters because we need to know what is available; also, `RunSync` sounds like a terrible idea (sync over async is very dangerous); frankly, `Exists` followed by `GetAsync` is *also* a bad idea, since that is a: two round trips, and b: an instance race condition; also - is it your intent to set a timeout just when *writing* the value? or also when *reading* the value for a rolling expiration? (both are possible)

Comment: @AlirezaMahmoudi How would i use `Add` with expiration, could you point me towards any documentation?

Comment: What is you redis client?

Comment: @MarcGravell I got this from the following github links: https://github.com/imperugo/StackExchange.Redis.Extensions
https://github.com/microsoftarchive/redis/releases/download/win-3.0.504/Redis-x64-3.0.504.msi

Comment: @AlirezaMahmoudi I got this from the following github links: github.com/imperugo/StackExchange.Redis.Extensions github.com/microsoftarchive/redis/releases/download/win-3.0.504

Comment: @Maiweb I'm not going to comment on the imperugo lib - nothing to do with me; however, if you use StackExchange.Redis: `StringSet` etc have optional parameters for setting key expiration as a `TimeSpan?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better to use `KeyExpire` function in `StackExchange`, so that Redis can handle the expiration by itself. I mean every where you add a key to cache it should be added with an expiration, so every time you fetch the key, if it is expired, the result is null and you can handle it.

code example is something like:

```
cache.Add("Key","Value1");
cache.KeyExpire("Key", new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
```

or

```
StringSetAsync("Key1", "Value1", new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30))
```

as suggested in comments. [Here is how](https://www.csharpcodi.com/csharp-examples/StackExchange.Redis.IDatabase.KeyExpire(StackExchange.Redis.RedisKey,%20System.Nullable,%20StackExchange.Redis.CommandFlags)/).

Comment: It is **hugely** preferable to use the atomic versions when possible; for example, `db.StringSetAsync("Key1", "Value1", new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30))` - note that SE.Redis does not have an `Add` method